# Facing problems in Clearcase 8 plugin for Eclipse Luna for config spec update

Tags: eclipse-plugin, clearcase

I have been using Eclipse Helios/Luna with plugin installation of clearcase plugin 8.0.1.x version and have imported the base code.
Recently, when trying to change the config-spec to update the build files, the process is running for hours continuously even without a single file.

Previously, we had Clearcase version as 7.0.x version and the corresponding plugin installed on Eclipse Helios without facing any issues.
But, have been facing issues during update of files after the upgrade of clearcase server to 8.0.x and with the corresponding client plugin in eclipse.

Also, tried manual update from repository for the whole folder. Still no luck.
But, if I know manually update the file one by one individually, it is going fine.
As the number of files in the project is more, it would not be efficient for us.

Can someone provide some alternatives to resolve this problem?

As a workaround, we have been creating new views everytime there is an update to the config-spec.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround would be to switch to [dynamic views](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8m0r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc%2Ftopics%2Ft_use_dyn_views.htm), supported in the latest 8.x version of ClearTeam/ClearCase. No reload needed with those kind of views.

The other would be to test with a minimal config spec, and load rules making sure you are loading only as few files as possible (jsut to check that those files do update when you change the config spec).

It can also depends on the exact version of your ClearCase installation.
There are some [patches for hanging issue](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27023148) (like "PM48668 Problem: The IBM Rational ClearTeam Explorer may hang intermittently when many views are started.")